# SQL Server: Remarks based on Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below Table:

```
Id  Status  Amount
1     A      100
2     A      200
3     R      300
4     R      400
5     A      500
```

then I have below query:

```
SELECT *
INTO #T1 
FROM #Temp 
WHERE Amount > 250
```

And

```
SELECT A.*
FROM #Temp A JOIN #T1 B ON A.Id = B.Id
WHERE A.Status ='A'
```

After these two query I am trying to get the status of each id.

Expected Result:

If I am giving input as a table

```
 Id
----
 2
 32
 4
 5
```

Expected Result:

```
Id    Remark
-----------------------
2     Failed with Amount     -- Amount is less that 250
32    Not found              -- Not available in the #temp table
4     Failed with Status     -- Status is R
5     Valid                  -- All condition passed
```

Sample Query to generate data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Id INT,
    Status NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Amount INT
)

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (1,'A',100)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (2,'A',200)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (3,'R',300)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (4,'R',400)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (5,'A',500)
```

I tried with Update but unable to get the all result as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Try `CASE..WHEN` with `outer join` as following:

```
SELECT #T1.ID,
CASE WHEN A.ID IS NULL THEN 'Not found'
WHEN A.STATUS <> 'A' THEN 'Failed with Status'
WHEN A.AMOUNT < 250 THEN 'Failed with Amount'
ELSE 'Valid' END AS REMARK
FROM (values (2,32,4,5)) as #T1(ID) LEFT JOIN #Temp A ON A.Id = #T1.Id;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I am passing `2,32,4,5` string as a input table

Comment: then you can use `(values (2,32,4,5)) #T1(B)` instead of `#T1`

Comment: You mean:  `(values (2), (32), (4), (5)) b(id)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Id INT,
    Status NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Amount INT
)

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (1,'A',100)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (2,'A',200)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (3,'R',300)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (4,'R',400)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (5,'A',500)
```

Input string

```
SELECT value as id into #t1 FROM  String_split('2,32,4,5', ',')
```

output query

```
SELECT b.Id
    , case
        when a.id is null then 'Not found'
        when a.Amount >250 and a.Status='A' then 'Valid' else 'Failed with Amount' 
      end as Remark         
FROM #Temp A 
right outer join #t1 b on a.Id =b.id
```